# Using page counter in \newtheorem

Tags: numbering, theorems, page-numbering, amsthm

I would like to use the page counter as a the first part of the label for definitions. I tried

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[page]
```

but that wouldn't work if the definition is at the top of a new page, presumably because of [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-wrongpn). Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `perpage` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,perpage,etoolbox}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\MakePerPage{definition}
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\theperpage.\arabic{definition}}
% We encourage TeX to break before a definition so the numbering will be correct
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{definition}{\goodbreak}

\usepackage[paperheight=60pt]{geometry} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
First on first page
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
Second on first page
\end{definition}

\newpage

\begin{definition}
First on second page
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

This will assign numbers 1.1, 1.2 and 2.1

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if one removes `\newpage` and adds (in the preamble) `\textheight=50pt`.

Comment: @lockstep The new version should work better

Comment: @vuce Yet it might fail in some circumstances; keep an eye on the numbering and if you find that some definition at the top of a page doesn't get numbered correctly, issue a `\pagebreak` before it. Please have a look at the [site FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq), particularly with respect to what voting means.